# ASP.NET Core 3.1 slow responses

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a standard ASP.NET Core 3.1 API application, which uses MVC controllers. The code is pretty straightforward, from the controller the code makes a query to MongoDb to retrieve a document. This is fast and pretty much okay. However, when I turned diagnostics on, I am seeing the request takes much longer than it should, the controller finishes it's work at 177ms while the final request finishes at 1068ms with a 204 response. See below for more information.

```
2020-09-22 18:16:48.5629|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Executed action method MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Post (MyProject.API), 
returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult in 177.3325ms.

2020-09-22 18:16:48.5938|4|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult.

2020-09-22 18:16:48.6289|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult|
Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 204

2020-09-22 18:16:48.6430|5|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult.

2020-09-22 18:16:48.6754|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Executed action MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Post (MyProject.API) in 735.1339ms

2020-09-22 18:16:48.6962|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|
Executed endpoint 'MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Post (MyProject.API)'

2020-09-22 18:16:48.7031|37|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|
Connection id "0HM2V3CUT1GMI" sending HEADERS frame for stream 
ID 15 with length 53 and flags END_STREAM, END_HEADERS

2020-09-22 18:16:48.7031||2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|
Request finished in 1068.2472ms 204
```

That's a huge difference there, approximately 890ms!
The above results are taken from a cold instance, so this was the first request that was received.
On a warm instance the difference is still significant (but not on the same scale).

```
2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Executed action method MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Get (MyProject.API), 
returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult in 11.4986ms.

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|4|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult.

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult|
Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 204

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|5|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult.

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|
Executed action MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Get (MyProject.API) in 36.8809ms

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|1|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|
Executed endpoint 'MyProject.API.Controllers.MyController.Get (MyProject.API)'

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|37|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|
Connection id "0HM2V3CUT1GMK" sending HEADERS frame for stream 
ID 1 with length 53 and flags END_STREAM, END_HEADERS

2020-09-22 18:24:24.9553|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|
Request finished in 124.9982ms 204
```

What I don't understand is why ASP.NET Core `ControllerActionInvoker` and Kestrel take so much time to return the response back! There's nothing custom in between, it's just native code. Any suggestions?

As side note, I have already implemented a warmup task, which loads all dependencies on application startup. I also have stripped unnecessary filters, input and output formatters and value providers, so the above results are the best I have achieved so far. Why though ASP.NET Core is so slow between returning the response from the controller, to writing the response to I/O and let it fly over the network?

Do I have to configure something in Kestrel? Do I have to improve something in MVC configuration?

Finally, as a side note, the code above is optimized, running on release build.

Comment: So the real question is why are diagnostics slowing down my query?  If you don't have on diagnostics the query and response are as fast as expected?  Could you show us the actual code that sets up the diagnostics and does the query instead of the log output?

Comment: No use unfortunately, I disabled diagnostics too and used New Relic to collect metrics. I'm still getting slow responses. Even if I comment out the code that does the query and simply return a result, still it's slow.

These two github issues on ASP.NET Core are related: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18005, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17985. In the first, a contributor suggests endpoint routing, which is fine, but why in the first place is the MVC framework so slow? Given the above, MVC is not recommended for applications with low latency demands.

Comment: When I say slow, I mean it takes more than it should be. I aim for <500ms responses but as you see from the above, I hardly get that. And it's inexplicable the response to take that long, after the controller is done. Between controller return and MVC internal processing of response, the timings are way far apart. 177.3325ms to 1068.2472ms is worlds apart.

Comment: Hard to comment on what you see for timing without seeing any code.  The issue link was someone about MVC adding 40 ms of overhead.  Without knowing what parameters they are deserializing and validating in that 40 ms it's hard to judge if that is an actual problem.  Like wise you have not shown any code either, so it's hard to judge what you are seeing.

Comment: @gdyrrahitis did you find solution? I'm fighting with similar problem, any respond with size more than 100 kB is very slow.

Comment: @hsd Unfortunately, I haven't found my answer. However I found a workaround and that was to drop controllers and use endpoints (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Less overhead. I also written some code to warmup the cold instance.